# Android: Speech recognition methods

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

So I'm writing a new app, in which I need to recognize a few words. I would like to know what method you recommend I use to meet these two requirements:

- I need the app to recognize roughly 50 words. Simple words like "blue", "red", "save", etc.
- It has to be done without the use of the Internet to access a server of some sort

From my research so far, it seems CMUSphinx is the best option.

Ideally, I would also like to make an app with a similar backend as a desktop application too (preferably Java based). As I understand it, CMUSphinx can achieve both my needs using PocketSphinx for my mobile app.

So what do you guys think would work best in my situation? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMUSpinx I think looks good. Note http://www.politepix.com/openears/ is also based on CMUSphinx a strong indicator.  However if there is a C++ library you could use NDK to run on Android but unlikely it would be better than CMUSphinx.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it out. I think I need the NDK for Sphinx too.